# R : Triple summation over function dependent on three indicies

Tags: r, sum, wolfram-mathematica, sapply

I am attempting to use R to to a triple summation over a function with three indices.

I was easily able to do this in Mathematica with the following code:

```
out = Sum[B[G[[k]]] * A[G[[k]], G[[j]], G[[i]]] * prod[G[[j]],G[[i]]],
          {k,1,Length[G]},{j,1,Length[G]},{i,1,Length[G]}]
```

where `G` is a matrix, and `B[.]`, `A[.]`, and `prod[.]` are all predefined functions.

In Mathematica, `Sum[f,{k,k_min, k_max}, {j,j_min, j_max}, {i, i_min, i_max}]` would evaluate the triple sum, Sum(k=k_min, k_max)[Sum(j=j_min, j_max)[Sum(i=i_min, i_max)[f]]], where `f` is some function.

I am now trying to do this in R and am having a lot of difficulty.  I have tried applying `sapply`with `sum` in the following manner, but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
guts.i.j.k <- function(i,j,k) B.k(k) * A.i.j.k(i, j, k) * prod.i.j(i, j)
innermostSum <- function(j,k) sum(sapply(1:length(G), FUN=guts.i.j.k, j=j, k=k ))
middleSum <- function(k) sum(sapply(1:length(G), FUN=innermostSum, k=k ))
outsideSum <- sum(sapply(1:length(G), FUN=middleSum))
return(outsideSum)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not good idea to use UpperCase single variables in M. Also, not good idea to use variables with `_` in them. Is your code actually as shown here? `Sum[f,{k,k_min, k_max}, {j,j_min, j_max}, {i, i_min, i_max}]`

Comment: No, the k_min ect. are not actually in my code.  I was trying to explain what the Sum[.] function did in case an R user was not familiar with Mathematica. The k_min represents k with the subscript of min.